# How do i feed 3 html select with jquery and json lists?

Tags: html, json, dropdown

The JS code below "programs" (html `<select id="programas">`) food or combo boxes with a list in Json (`list-region-programs.json`) according to a combination choice of "regions" (html `<select id="regioes">`).

But how do I feed or combobox "combo-based" municipalities (html `<select id="municipios">`) in "regions" with a Json list `combox-municipios.json`?

choose 1 program -> feed regions -> select 1 region -> feed "county" (3 nested combos).

**HTML**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- dropdown Regiões -->
  <label for="regioes">Região</label>
  <select id="regioes">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
  
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- dropdown Programas -->
  <label for="programas">Programa </label>
  <select id="programas">
 </select>
  </div>
```

**JS JSON**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('SIGPLAM2/javaScript/lista-regiao-programas.json', function(data){
 var items = [];
 var options = '<option value="">escolha uma regiÃ£o</option>';

    $.each(data, function(key, val){
   options += '<option value="' + val.nome + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
 });

    $("#regioes").html(options);
 $("#regioes").change(function(){
   var options_programas = '';
   var str = "";

   $("#regioes option:selected").each(function(){
  str += $(this).text();
   });

   $.each(data, function(key, val){
  if(val.nome == str){
    $.each(val.cidades, function(key_city, val_city){
   options_programas += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
    });
  }
   });
     
   $("#programas").html(options_programas);

 }).change();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... 3 html select combobox dropdown with javascript

Function: Select a region (regioes) -> complete program (programas) -> select a program -> complete city (municipio)

```js
function get_json_data(id, parent_id) {
  var html_code = '';

  $.getJSON('SIGPLAM4/javaScript/lista-regiao-programas-municipio.json', function(data){
    ListName = id;  // ID do select regioes
    html_code += '<option value="">Selecione a ' + ListName + '</option>';
    
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      if (value.parent_id == parent_id) {
        html_code += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>';
      }
    });
    $('#' + id).html(html_code);
  });
}
get_json_data('regioes',0);

$(document).on('change', '#regioes', function(){
  var regioes_id = $(this).val();

  if (regioes_id != ''){
    get_json_data('programas', regioes_id);
    get_json_data('municipio', category_id);
    get_json_data('municipioSuas', category_id);
    get_json_data('municipioVig', category_id);
  } else {
    $('#programas').html('<option value="">Selecione o programa</option>');
  }
});

$(document).on('change', '#programas', function(){
  var category_id = $(this).val();
  if (category_id != '') {
    get_json_data('municipio', category_id);
    get_json_data('municipioSuas', category_id);
    get_json_data('municipioVig', category_id);
  } else {
    $('#municipio').html('<option value="">Selecione o municipio</option>');
    $('#municipioSuas').html('<option value="">Selecione o municipio SUAS</option>');
    $('#municipioVig').html('<option value="">Selecione o municipio VIG</option>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Answers which explain what changed are downvoted less often than those which simply show code that works without explanation. See [answer].